# Deploy multiple projects to single azure virtual machine from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, web-deployment, azure-virtual-machine

I have a single azure windows and SQL server virtual machine and I want to publish multiple ASP.NET projects in one solution on it (on separate ports). I have accomplished to deploy one of the projects via visual studio web deploy on port 80 (Default Web Site on IIS) easily (I've used this link https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/AspNetVMs/docs/publish-web-app-from-visual-studio.md), but I couldn't find a way to configure publish configuration for the other projects in the solution to deploy them on other ports on that same VM. How can I do this via publish tooling of visual studio?

Comment: None of this is about Azure nor VMs. Your question is about deploying a multiple web applications to a single IIS server. Each project deployed to different websites in a single IIS server, each website binding to a different port on the same IP, or you can provision multiple IPs to the Windows Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you aware of deploying website to Azure VM from Visual Studio so i am not covering that in the answer.

As rightly said by Ricardo in the comment that " Each project deployed to different websites in a single IIS server, each website binding to a different port on the same IP, or you can provision multiple IPs to the Windows Server".

Basically when you try to publish website from VS then a window would come up like below:

[image]

Where you can change the setting by clicking below link:

[image]

you can change the binding and port information and you can deploy it.

You have to ensure that port is open for incoming communication.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/publish-web-app-from-visual-studio

Hope it helps.